# Is there a way to pass a PHP value to JavaScript?

Tags: users, javascript

I have a link generated within a JavaScript file that contains the following code:

```
jQuery(".url").append('<a href='+ path +'/extra/home><img src='+ pathimage +'></a>');
```

I would like to alter the path variables when user is not logged. In Drupal terms this would look like: `global $user; if (user->uid == 0) {..redirect page.}` or `global $user; return !(bool) $user->uid;`

How can I use the `$user->uid` property with JavaScript code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7). You can use it to pass data from PHP to JavaScript. Something like the following should suffice:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_init().
 */
function modulename_init() {
  if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
    drupal_add_js(array(
      'modulename' => array(
        'path' => $logged_out_path
      )
    ), 'setting');
  }
}
```

Note that I am calling this from within an implementation of hook_init(), but really you can do this anywhere, be it from a module or a theme. Also note that I have provided a sufficient namespace for the value to live (i.e. within 'modulename' => 'path'). This will make it clear from JavaScript's point of view exactly who owns the variable (i.e. which module it came from), but more importantly will help to prevent collisions with settings in other modules.

From JavaScript you can access the value of $logged_out_path like this:

```
var path = Drupal.settings.modulename.path;
```

Comment: This is what Drupal core does with `Drupal.settings.basePath`, which contains its base path. The code suggested in this answer doesn't expose sensitive information to JavaScript code. The important is that the module code doesn't assume the user reaching `$logged_out_path` has a specific role, or permission.

Comment: Thanks I found a way via context: conditions > user role > anonymous then reactions > theme_html that help me provide a class for body tag when is anonymous